# Password input with custom button

Tags: html

I am currently trying to add my own login button to my password box and I can't get them to link together. I'd appreciate any help on Password Inputs and custom buttons.

Here is my password input:

```
<label class="hidden-label" for="Passwd"></label>
<input id="Passwd" name=" Passwd" type="password" placeholder=" Password" 
   class="" style="width: 275px; height: 43px;"/>
```

And here is my button:

```
<a href="login.php" class="button blue" >Sign in</a>
```

I am also using CSS to make it look like I want it to.

Comment: you are using a link as a button.  You probably want to have a [read of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms) and the articles linking from it

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the data from your password field to the login page, you are to wrap your label and input inside a `form` with the attribute `action="login.php"`.

The button should either be a `<button>` or an input with `type="submit"`.

Otherwise there is no way for your code to tell to pass data to the login.php page.

```
<form action="login.php">
    <label class="hidden-label" for="Passwd"></label>
    <input id="Passwd" name=" Passwd" type="password" placeholder=" Password" class="" style="width: 275px; height: 43px;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="button blue">
</form>
```

Fore more infos read this: [W3schools Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)